# How to print mysql data as it is using php?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

If I run this MySql query:

```
EXPLAIN some_table;
```

It would print something like this on the mysql prompt:

```
+-------+------+------+
| Field | Col2 | Col3 |
+-------+------+------+
| ...   | ...  | ...  |
+-------+------+------+
```

In PHP using PDO, I would have to fetch the result using -

```
$pdo = ("localhost", "gourab", "");
$q = "EXPLAIN some_table";
$out = $pdo->query($q);
$fetch = $out->fetchAll();
```

And I would need to use the `$fetch` laboriously to present the result.

My question is that how can I just dump the data returned by MySQL like

```
+-------+------+------+
| Field | Col2 | Col3 |
+-------+------+------+
| ...   | ...  | ...  |
+-------+------+------+
```

, in PHP. (as it is)

Thanks!

Cheers!

Comment: MySQL the _server_ does not return that formatted table. That table is what you see when you use the `mysql` command line _client_, which formats it in a way it assumes useful for a terminal user. From the server's perspective, PDO is also just a client, and the two are more or less indistinguishable. To get that output you would either need to produce it yourself, or far less desirably, call the `mysql` command line client from within PHP via one of the shell process functions.

Comment: Alright, so should I delete the question now?

Comment: No I wouldn't say so, and I didn't vote to close, because someone may come along with an easy solution to get a formatted table without much work.

Comment: Alright then... Thanks although!